# How continuous cin input works in C++

Tags: c++

I'm sorry but I could't find a better title for this question. I'm following Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practice using C++. This example code came to my attention. My question is, how does cin identify two different types in one single word like 200.40i (200.40 double and i char)? I mean, shouldn't it be expecting at least an empty-space separated input?

```
int main()
{
    constexpr double cm_per_inch = 2.54;
    double length = 1;
    char unit = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a length followed by a unit (c or i):\n";
    cin >> length >> unit;
    if (unit == 'i')
        cout << length << "in == " << cm_per_inch*length << "cm\n";
    else
        cout << length << "cm == " << length/cm_per_inch << "in\n";
}
```

If i just run the program and type in: 200.40i works fine, same for:    200.40 i and for: 200.40 \n i.

Comment: `i` can’t appear there in any representation of a `double` that `>>` will parse, so it knows the `double` ends there. It’s really fragile, though – try replacing `i` with `e`. Stream input needs lots of error checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gross oversimplification of the inner working of the formatted input extraction operator, a.k.a. `>>` that serves to explain the input behavior you're observing. This is how `>>` works:

Step 1: skip over any whitespace in the input stream.

Step 2: convert the next portion of the input stream to whatever datatype `>>` is going to. Extract from the input stream ***only*** the input that's converted.

These two steps are executed for every `>>` operator. As I said, this is oversimplification. There are other things that are going on, such as a sentry object for exception handling which are irrelevant here.

The important thing is that the `>>` does not "stop" when it sees whitespace following whatever was extracted. That's how the `>>` is often explained, in introductory C++ texts, but it's not quite right. The `>>` stop as soon as it finishes extracting whatever's extracted, and does ***not*** extract whatever follows it. Now, following "whatever's extracted" you would often have additional whitespace. That's fine. The formatted input extraction operator will stop at that point. But the important thing is that it will ***not*** extract the whitespace. That's going to be dealt with by the ***subsequent*** `>>` extraction (if there is one).

And it doesn't have to be whitespace. It could be anything that's no longer parsed as whatever's getting extracted. So, in your case:

```
cin >> length >> unit;
```

`length` is a `double`. `unit` is a `char`. Your input is:

```
200.40i
```

The first `>>` extracts only "200.40". The character `i` can't possibly belong to the `double` value, so extraction stops at that point, and the `i` is ***not*** extracted. So that the only thing that the first `>>` pulls out of it. Then, the 2nd `>>` extracts the lone "i" character.

The formatted extraction operator, for all practical purposes, always [uses peek() to look at the next character in the input stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) in order to decide whether to extract it as part of whatever's being extracted from the input stream. And if it look good, then it gets gobbled up.

Now, if there was some whitespace:

```
200.40 i
```

The first `>>` takes the `double` out of it, just like before, and stops, but it does not extract the space. The ***2nd*** `>>` skips the whitespace as part of its "Step 1", and then extracts the `char`.

So, you see, the `>>` formatted extraction operator discards whitespace not ***after*** it extracts whatever it extracts, but ***before***.

A few other notes:

- If the `>>` extracts into a `std::string`, this extracts anything except whitespace, so the only thing that stops extraction here is trailing whitespace. But the trailing whitespace itself still isn't extracted then, but only by the next `>>` operator.
- if, as in this case, `>>` extract into a lonely `char`, this `char` can only hold one character, so that's all that's going to get extracted, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/5-10-stdcin-extraction-and-dealing-with-invalid-text-input/

When the extraction operator is used, the following procedure happens:

1. If there is data already in the input buffer, that data is used for extraction.
2. If the input buffer contains no data, the user is asked to input data for extraction (this is the case most of the time). When the user hits enter, a ‘\n’ character will be placed in the input buffer.
3. operator>> extracts as much data from the input buffer as it can into the variable (ignoring any leading whitespace characters, such as spaces, tabs, or ‘\n’).
4. Any data that can not be extracted is left in the input buffer for the next extraction.

So in your example `200.40` will be extracted and converted to double. As input buffer will still have `i` it will be extracted into char.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand how it works you need a little knowledge of Object-Oriented Programming.

In C++ `cin` is an object.


But you might ask, what is an object?

Basically an object is a data structure that can be manipulated with various operators:

e.g. `+` `-` `*` `/` `%` `<<` `>>` etc.

The two types of objects in C++ are: `built-in type` and `user-defined type`.


You're using objects all the time in C++ whether you know it or not!

For example, your variable `length` is an object of built-in type `double`.


Now what can you do with `length`?

Well it supports the `+` `-` `*` `/` and more.

It's a very intuitive type.


Now what about `cin`?

`cin` is an object of user-defined type `istream`.

And we know that it supports the operator `>>` which is known as the bitwise right-shift operator.

This operator (in `cin`'s case) takes the given input data and spits it (shifts it) into your variable.


A feature of this operator is that you can chain multiple variables:

e.g. `cin >> variable1 >> variable2 >> variable3;`

Just as you can with operator `+` in an object of type double:

e.g. `length + 1 + 2 + 3;`


But each variable in the chain must be separated by the `>>` operator.